# Sourcetree copiar rutas relativas de las clases de un commit

Tags: rutas, sourcetree

Hola en Sourcetree Desktop cuando selecciono un commit me salen las clases ordenadas por file status. ¿Hay alguna forma de copiar la ruta relativa de todas las clases y copiarlas en un txt?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando selecciono una clase modificada me sale la opción "Copy Path to Clipboard" le doy click y lo copio en un notepad y me sale toda la ruta absoluta pero en el Sourcetree sale la ruta relativa.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Le doy a varias clases modificadas le doy click derecho y ya no me sale la opción "Copy Path to Clipboard" me sale la opción custom actions y no deja copiar la ruta relativa de varios elementos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hace ya casi 2 años atrás algunas personas solicitaron lo que tu preguntas y al parecer nunca se ha implementado https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREE-7703, Visual Studio Code si cuenta con esto utilizando extensiones como git graph.